# Excel interop MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, excel, exception, interop

In my C# program, I am using Excel 2010 interop assembly. With this i am reading & writing data to excel file. And executing fine on dev box (contains Office 2010). On client machine, even though they have Office 2010 and Office PIA, there are seeing below exception, raises at WriteToExcel() method call.

```
Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Type System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetTypeFromCLSID(System.GUID)'.
```

Below is my code snippet.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args){

       // read user input, process and write data to Excel
       WriteToExcel();
 }

[STAThread]
static void WriteToExcel(){
     Application xlsApplication = new Application();
     Workbook xlsWorkbook = xlsApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath);
     // write data to excel
     // close up            
 }
```

Comment: Can you debug on the client machine? Also did Furqan's answer work?

Comment: Install .NET 4.5 on that machine.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point, maybe the OP has 4.5 installed on dev machine, and is targeting 4.0 (on the client machine) and this is a bug which is being masked because 4.5 replaces the 4.0 compiler, and therefore masks bugs in 4.0?

Comment: Thanks @JMK for the tip. Issue solved after lowering .net version to 4.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Issue solved after lowering .net version to 4.0. Earlier My devbox has 4.5 and application is compiled with this version. My client machine has 4.0 version, lowering .net version solved the issue.

Comment: This may seem obvious to everyone except me, but simply lower the "Target Framework" setting on the Application properties page in VS.
I initially thought it was required to uninstall 4.5 and install 4.0 in my dev enviro.

Comment: Thank you for posting this answer. I was having the same target framework issue and didn't realize it until I read your post.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code:

```
[STAThread]
static void WriteToExcel()
{
    Application xlsApplication = new Application();
    var missing = System.Type.Missing;
    Workbook xlsWorkbook = xlsApplication.Workbooks.Open(excelFilePath, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
    // write data to excel
    // close up            
 }
```